# Change a link on page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I need a small help replacing the url in a given page.

I am using athis board which uses some external content and it comes with some links like :

"To learn more about this, visit our [FAQ](http://www.xyz.cofaqs) Page."

My issue is that The word [FAQ](http://www.xyz.cofaqs) has a link in it which points to lets say `http://www.xyz.com/faqs` Now I want to do 2 things with it:

1. I want to change that link to `http://www.mydomain.com/faqsection`.
2. I want the link to open in a new window.

**UPDATE:**

The actual code is like this :

`<a onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" title="FAQ" href="/postFAQ">FAQ</a>
Page.`

I would want to replace the complete `"/postFAQ"` part to  `http://www.mydomain.com/faqsection`.

I am using jQuery in my application, hence is it possible to do this using some jQuery script?

Comment: Do you want to do this for any external link? Or just this link? How is the mapping, i.e. `faqs -> faqsection`, and do you have such a mapping for every external link?

Comment: I would personally avoid altering href's on links using jQuery - not because its hard, but because not everyone has JavaScript, especially crawlers like GoogleBot

Comment: Hi @Felix and @gnarf thanks for the post. I have updated the post with actual acript please have a look at the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the attribute selector:

```
$('a[href="/postFAQ"]').attr('href', 'http://www.mydomain.com/faqsection');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your FAQ tag is like this:

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com/faqs">FAQ</a>
```

You can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("a").each(function(e){
    if(jQuery(this).text() == "FAQ"){//Very bad way!!
      jQuery(this).attr({"href":"http://www.mydomain.com/faqsection", 
            "target":"_blank"});
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Avoid calling `jQuery(this)` multiple times in the same context - instead you should [cache your selectors](http://blog.seankoole.com/qotd-why-should-you-cache-when-using-jquery)

Comment: Hey @Naveed thanks for the help. Sorry for missing it earlier, my actual code is like this `<a onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" title="FAQ" href="/postFAQ">FAQ</a>
Page.` Kindly help.

Comment: @Vikram okay you can do: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("a").click(function(e){
    if(jQuery(this).text() == "FAQ"){//Very bad way!!
     e.preventDefault();      window.open(http://www.mydomain.com/faqsection");
    }
  });
});`

Comment: Thanks will try and keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

1) Give your link an id, e.g:

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" title="FAQ" href="/postFAQ" id="faqLink">FAQ</a> Page.
```

2) Do the following in Jquery:

```
$("#faqLink").attr({href :"http://newlink.com", target: "_BLANK"});
```